# How to redirect all requests to wp-login.php?

Tags: redirect, wp-login-form

I created some custom login/registration template pages and now I want that every request to wp-login.php to be redirected to a custom url. Now I have something like this:

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
 function possibly_redirect(){
global $pagenow;
if( '/wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
wp_redirect('/login');
exit();
}
}
```

but it doesn't work properly because when I click a logout link (in a meta widget) it will redirect me to the /login link and not doing logout. Do you have other method to do this in a safe or a better way ?
Thank you.

Comment: Add `if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'logout' ) return;` for example.

Answer (score 7):

To restrict direct access only for 'wp-login.php', without POST or GET request (useful for custom ajax login forms), I use the advanced function:

```
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ||   // in case of LOGIN
      ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    // in case of REGISTER
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found the right way to do this.

For redirect wordpress login to a custom url:

```
function redirect_login()
{
wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) );
exit(); 
}
add_action( 'login_form_login', 'redirect_login' );
```

For redirect wordpress registration to a custom url:

```
 function redirect_register()
{
wp_redirect( home_url( '/registration' ) );
exit(); 
}
add_action( 'login_form_register', 'redirect_register' );
```

I think the code is very simple to understand, basically you add hooks for login and register url's and then use wp-redirect to redirect to a custom url. All requests to wp-login.php and wp-login.php?action=register will be redirected to the custom url's you set.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend John's answer, having `exit()` omitted. So, the code that is fully functional in my case is:

```
function redirect_login() {
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) ); 
}
add_action( 'login_form_login', 'redirect_login' );
```

It seems that the `exit()` is making it impossible for a user to login.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note from the WP function reference for `wp_redirect()`...

1. an `exit;` is indeed part of the usage, and
2. `$location` parameter is to be the "Absolute URI", one including the protocol (`http://`)
   Example of Absolute/Full URI: `http://www.example.com/blog/images/icecream.jpg`